# TV out window in iPad simulator disappears on landscape mode

Tags: iphone, ios-simulator

I'm making an app for the iPad with TV output to an extra screen. Everything works fine, but for some reason the TV out window disappears when I put the iPad in landscape mode. I commented all the code that makes it go to landscape automatically but as soon as I rotate in iPhone simulator, the tv output window goes away.

Is it just not possible to have the device in landscape mode with an extra screen or is there something I'm overlooking?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I've noticed there's a CALayer use-after-release bug in iOS7.0.3 simulator when you have setup an External Screen triggering at some point, but a later iOS7.1 fixes that.  Can you confirm if you have the problem with iOS 7.1 ?